# Does spring-boot-gradle-plugin moves with the spring-boot version?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, gradle-plugin

Hi in the official documentation is given the following snipet:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
    }

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
```

If we use spring-boot-gradle-plugin do we have to follow this practice both versions boot and boot-plugin to be the same?
What will happen if the versions are not the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Boot build plugins (both Gradle and Maven) always followed the Spring Boot version. Yes, they have to match the Spring Boot version you are using.